# Executing command with powershell

Tags: powershell

Beginner question power shell.
How can I execute a command with an @ in it in powershell?
This works fine in a dos window:

```
curl --ntlm -d @somejson_ok.json --header `"Content-Type: application/json`" -u : -X POST http://localhost/someaction
```

How can I run this with powershell? I tried:

```
$command = "curl --ntlm -d @somejson_ok.json --header `"Content-Type: application/json`" -u : -X POST http://localhost/someaction"
iex $command
Read-Host "Done"
```

Error: Der Splat-Operator "@" kann nicht dazu verwendet werden, auf Variablen in einem Ausdruck zu verweisen.
Help appreciated :)

Comment: `@somejson_ok.json` -> `'@somejson_ok.json'`

Comment: Tnx: now this error Invoke-WebRequest : Der Parameter kann nicht verarbeitet werden, da der Parametername "u" nicht eindeutig ist.
Mögliche Übereinstimmungen:  -UseBasicParsing -Uri -UseDefaultCredentials -UserAgent.. Where does the Invoke-WebRequest coming from. It seems like a different version of curl than in a dos window?

Comment: If I replace "-u : " with "-UseDefaultCredentials" then the following error is thrown: Invoke-WebRequest : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "@somejson_ok.json" akzeptiert.

Comment: `curl` -> `curl.exe`. In PowerShell `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`. if you want to use the Windows port of cURL specify the command with its extension.

Comment: Tnx, that works :)